# Docker root permissions level queries

Tags: docker

All my questions are w.r.t to LATEST version of DOCKER

1. Daemon still need to run as a root right?
2. Every user having access to Docker group, has root permissions?  So, there is no difference at all between original root user and user having permissions to Docker group. If there are differences, what are they?
3. So, with authorization plugins you just restrict access of a user to Docker daemon but not to the other permissions that the user has on host? (Assuming the user in this Docker group/user having access to Docker daemon has root permissions on the host - my previous question)
4. Is there any link between "runc, containerd" and "docker daemon running as a root"?  or else are these (runc,containerd) introduced only for supporting OCI format? I had a stupid thought that these are introduced for eliminating docker running as a root - I am sure this is wrong but need a confirmation.

Comment: Note: (2.5 years later) `dockerd` does not need `root` anymore in the next Docker release: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521566/6309

Answer (score 0):

```
Daemon still need to run as a root right?
```

Update Feb. 2019: no, it does not need root anymore!
See "[Install Docker binary on a server without root access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521566/6309)"

---

Original answer (Jul. 2016)

Yes, you can see it in "[Configuring and running Docker on various distributions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/)", even though [it adds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/#/daemonless-containers):

> Starting with Docker 1.12 containers can run without Docker or `containerd` running.
>   This allows the Docker daemon to exit, be upgraded, or recover from a crash without affecting running containers on the system.
>   To enable this functionality you need to add the `--live-restore` flag when launching `dockerd`. This will ensure that Docker does not kill containers on graceful shutdown or on restart leaving the containers running.

```
Every user having access to Docker group, has root permissions?
So, there is no difference at all between original root user
and user having permissions to Docker group?
```

Not exactly. The docker daemon will make the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the `docker` group when the daemon starts

As mentioned in "[Docker daemon attack surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#/docker-daemon-attack-surface)" (still for 1.12)

> only trusted users should be allowed to control your Docker daemon.
>
> You can start a container where the `/host` directory will be the `/` directory on your host; and the container will be able to alter your host filesystem without any restriction.

So a user part of the docker group is *not* root. But it has access to all containers which can mount anything from the host. Which is... pretty close to root.

```
So, with authorization plugins you just restrict access of a user to Docker daemon
but not to the other permissions that the user has on host?
```

The "[authorization plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/)" page [has not changed significantly](https://github.com/docker/docker/commits/master/docs/extend/plugins_authorization.md) since docker 1.11.
The main change is:

> If TLS is enabled in the [Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/), the default user authorization flow extracts the user details from the certificate subject name.
>   +That is, the `User` field is set to the client certificate subject common name, and the `AuthenticationMethod` field is set to `TLS`.

```
Is there any link between "runc, containerd" and
"docker daemon running as a root"? 
or else are these (`runc`,`containerd`) introduced only for supporting OCI format?
```

There is with [issue 15187 "User namespaces - Phase 1"](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15187) and [`runc` PR 160](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/pull/160)

> The prestart hook is run after the container process is up (cloned into new namespaces) but before the user command (for e.g. bash) is executed. That allows someone to do something useful in the namespaces of the container.

```
I had a stupid thought that these are introduced for eliminating docker running as a root
```

This will be more likely achieved through user namespace.
The userns (usernamespace) [seems still experimental](https://github.com/estesp/docker/blob/930b27a86bf02969600259ce3a5d3fcff10edcb5/experimental/userns.md) (from [PR 12648](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12648))

Comment: 4. I really dint understand how prestart hook is related to my question. 

5. I am looking for eliminating running Docker daemon as root with runc, containerd but not inside the container. I knew that inside container user namespaces help. Can you try to re-read this too?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your patience in answering my questions

Comment: @innocentme 2. Yes, other other operations are not permitted... at first. Once you mount a filesystem and change a script as root, you become root.

Comment: @innocentme 4. prestart will allow to restrict the user namespace, preventing any operation as root. In that aspect, runc is linked to "docker daemon running as a root"

Comment: @innocentme as far as I know, for now, the docker daemon is still running as root, even with runc and containerd.

Comment: 1. I will see the details about prestart. 
2. Did you understand my question on auth plugins? 
3. Well, yes I think runc and containerd are introduced just for supporting OCI but not for eliminating docker daemon running as root.

Comment: @innocentme Regarding 2 and the auth plugin, I don't have much information about it. I suspect it deserve its own question.